# How do I change image of button when pressed xcode 7 / Swift 2?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2, xcode7

I have this so far and don't know what to do next.I currently have a button in my view controller with an image (play image) and want to change it to pause image when clicked.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class VesuviusViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var PausePlay: UIButton!



@IBAction func playPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    VesSet()

}
```

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26837371/how-to-change-uibutton-image-in-swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add it inside your button click action

```
sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "play.png")!, forState: .Normal)
```

Comment: Someone down voted without the reason.

Answer (score 0):

```
  @IBAction func playPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    VesSet()



        sender.selected = !_btnCheckbox.selected;//put the appropriate  login of swift to do that 

        //checkbox
        sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "play.png")!, forState: .Normal)

       sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "pause.png")!, forState: .selected)


    }
```