# How to change button into a picture?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

Does anyone know how to turn a picture of some sort into a `UIButton`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change UIButton image in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26837371/how-to-change-uibutton-image-in-swift)

Answer (score 1):

Programmatically:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "image")
btn.setImage(btnImage , forState: .normal)
```

Storyboard:
Select your image > Attributes inspector > Image

Answer (score 0):

You can do this properly by adding a tap gesture recognizer to your `UIImageView` and linked the gesture to an action

```
@IBAction func actionImageTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add TapGestureRecognizer in your UIImageView. That way you can add some event on touch event like button.