# im working on favourites in swift, on favorite_btn click i want to change the image of the button from star to star.fill

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on favourites in swift, on favourites button click I want to change the image of the button from star to star.fill which are system images, I put on main story board the star image and in my code I want onClick favoris button to change the image into star.fill, there is my code

```
  @IBAction func add Favoris(_ sender: Any) {
        favoris_ button. imageView?.image = UIImage(systemName: "star.fill")

        }
```

But it doesn't work, any help please?

Comment: Check this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26837371/how-to-change-uibutton-image-in-swift

Comment: in that example they are working on image assets, but what I want to work with is system images, but thank you for your help :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change UIButton image in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26837371/how-to-change-uibutton-image-in-swift)

Comment: already resolved, check Tanjima's answer, thank you at anyways :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@IBAction func addFavoris(_ sender: Any) {
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            favoris_button.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "star.fill"), for: .normal)
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Yafet Here is your answer. I hope this will helps you