# Change the shape of check buttons in UITableView in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am relatively new to ios. I am seeking help on the possibility to change the shape of the check button as the image asset that I was provided with comes in a rounded rectangle image. Is it possible to even do so in iOS? I have been looking around for solutions but to no avail.

This is the existing UI which is enabled with the default check button

[image]

This is the round rectangle check button that I would like to change to

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could change it with different image for select/unselected state.

For advance, you could render those by drawing custom CALayers and change the shape, button, check's position programmatically

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Are there any resources that you can recommend for me to refer to for implementation in objective c?

Comment: You can try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26837371/how-to-change-uibutton-image-in-swift

Comment: OK thank you for that information. I will try it out